# The Motionless Floating Eraser

Tags: lateral-thinking, science

First question here; I hope this question fits the [rules](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5884/2062) well :)

So, first please see the two images below:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

As you can find yourself, the eraser appears to **float motionless** over the register's page, with **more than half** of its area outside the contact area with the register. This picture has not been modified. The eraser is a normal unmodified brand new cuboid eraser found in stores.

Don't be bewildered :) This is possible; and these pictures are from my own experiment.

**Question**: How is this possible? Or how have I done this?
**Answer**:

> Of course, that you have to find! ;)

Please post your answer along with a picture (just as I have) of the eraser floating in air explaining what you did. Remember that the eraser has to float over a register kept over a table.

There is only one definite answer (at least, I believe there is). Happy solving :-)

**EDIT:**
So, after thinking that I could bewilder you all with my original puzzle, I am bewildered myself. I tried to be as clear as possible. First as [I was told](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/the-motionless-floating-eraser#comment19051_6000) that one definite answer should be there, so I edited the question to state that just one definite answer is there to my knowledge. I clearly stated that the eraser is motionless, still I [get a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/the-motionless-floating-eraser#comment19085_6004) that a [man is floating](https://www.flickr.com/photos/barbar/4470877212/) in air like this eraser. I tell that the eraser is unmodified, still I [get answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6007/2062) [breaking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6002/2062) this rule. I tell that this is a real world situation, still I get an answer that the background image is [tilted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6008/2062). People are breaking what I say. Is this my fault? And then I am told that the question is too broad so we are closing it.

I thought that I would explore some new ideas. I tried to be as positive as possible, but I guess I can't handle this much negativity. Too remove all scopes of this question being reopened, I answer the question myself:

[image]

The center of gravity is maintained by the compass with a pencil. In the rush of closing this question, none of you thought of this, which I thought would be too easy for the genius people here.

Thank you everyone. and Good bye.

Comment: Sorry, but "explore the different (creative) ways in which this is possible" isn't what we're looking for in challenge questions. Puzzles here should have a definite answer, not invite a bunch of different answers.

Comment: I want to add that you clearly made an effort to find and follow the rules, and it's our fault for not having guidelines like the one I mentioned written clearly and in one place. We're still trying to figure out what we're about and how to convey that to new users. So, even if this question doesn't work out here, I encourage you to stay around and post more.

Comment: @xnor Hello! I said "different creative ways" because (1) accepting one definite answer might be limiting the answer set inviting downvotes. (2) The creative people here can think anything! However, if this is not acceptable, I will change it. Thank you!

Comment: What is a register?  It looks like a white table.

Comment: @McMagister The table is the brown one. The [register](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=657&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=notebook&btnG=&search_plus_one=form&oq=notebook&gs_l=img.12..0l10.2019.6620.0.7479.15.13.0.0.0.0.337.1033.0j1j1j2.4.0.msedr...0...1c.1.58.img..11.4.1028.RO7lGJt78H4#imgdii=_) is a white register; it just doesn't have lines. Be assured it is not anything else. A register is also called notebook/copy in some countries.

Comment: Oh so its a notebook.  Will any book do?

Comment: @McMagister Yes, any book/notebook will do, provided it is kept on the table the way I have kept it as you can see in the picture.

Comment: "The center of gravity is maintained by the compass with a pencil" I don't understand.  Where is the compass and where is the pencil?

Comment: @McMagister I posted another one if the first is not clear. There should be three images now in total. 2 initial; one new.

Comment: Hi, please don't take it harshly. It's a clever question, and being closed is only about the issue of multiple plausible answers - e.g. I don't see why glue wouldn't solve it. Sorry about the "welcome", please do hang around (get it :D).

Comment: @d'alar'cop Yes. I will do some yoga. I don't get disappointed so easily. I do believe you can expect me to come back and post another puzzle.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You say that the eraser is “**floating over**” the register, but the photo shows it **laying on** the register. “Floating” implies that the eraser is not in contact with the book or the table. Your solution does not have the eraser floating.

Comment: @Gilles The words are: "the eraser appears to float motionless". I don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: @GaurangTandon. In the question and one of your comments, you say that the eraser is "unmodified". But the third picture shows that it clearly *has* been modified (by having a counter-balance stuck in it). This solution seems quite similar to several of the suggested answers, making me wonder whether you're playing an elaborate game of double-bluff. So come on: tell us what the *real* solution is :-)

Comment: @ekhumoro Along with that compass and blower thing, there's a very thin thread running from the register straight to the table mixing quite well with the patterns on the floor and thus it can't be easily seen. Even I can't see it :P But, after reviewing this situation closely, I can say that the question does invite too many answers and thus has been rightfully closed.

Comment: @GaurangTandon This being said, your solution is at least as clever and easy to realize as the other answers given.

Answer (score 8):

A few possibilities that spring to mind, some more practical than others:

1. Eraser is in the process of falling at the moment the photo is taken (shutter speed of 1/250 or faster will 'freeze' motion).
2. Photo is taken in 0-g or low-g environment e.g. space station, descending aircraft, descending lift.
3. Surface tension: water, oil, etc.
4. Static electricity.
5. Frame of reference is rotating (picture is sideways, camera is spinning with other equipment), Coriolis force is in play. E.g. all equipment is on a wheeled trolley being spun around fast.
6. Wind: a fan below the frame of the photo is pushing air upwards; a vacuum cleaner above the frame of the photo is pulling air upwards.
7. Black hole outside frame of photo is causing gravity distortion.
8. Descriptive text is untrue: picture has been modified, eraser has been modified (e.g. hollowed out at one end to shift centre of gravity, concealed magnet, etc etc).
9. Rubber has perished, stuck itself to the paper.
10. Glue.

That's before we even get onto the possibilities of parallel universes....

Comment: Nice! But points 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, and 10 are clearly not true. Point 4: I don't think it's possible. You may try yourself. Point: 6: That's a good one. I didn't think of it. It can be possible other than the solution I thought.  But note that the eraser is *motionless*, wind might move/shake it...

Comment: btw, sixth point is [mine](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6003) :)

Comment: Clearly 1 to 9 are only to create a dramatic effect.  The essence of the message is that glue is the obvious answer that comes to mind to everybody.

Comment: I think that the point 7 must be the true! :)

Comment: Either 1 works as a concept, or this man is floating stationary in midair: https://www.flickr.com/photos/barbar/4470877212/

Comment: with so many answers you feel equally answer this thing, I'd assume you voted to close as too broad - not that it's any of my business :p

Comment: @d'alar'cop, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oz8RjPAD2Jk

Comment: If we're speaking in memes, lol: http://i.imgur.com/UDaO9eB.jpg

Comment: Oh, that's ok if the answer is tongue-in-cheek. ;)

Comment: Turns out #8 was the correct answer: the eraser had been modified by having a compass stuck in it, to move the centre of gravity.

Answer (score 7):

1. glue or anything sticky
2. a magnet in a hole in the eraser
3. lead in a hole in the eraser
4. a hidden paperclip stuck between the pages
5. a thumbtack

There are too many answers.

This is an unfolded paper clip stuck between the pages.

[image: paperclip solution]

OK, a new possibility:

6. A glass table.

Comment: You can view yourself that nothing of this sort can be seen in the picture I posted. The contact area is too small for these things to happen, and the rubber can fall off easily. Think something creative! The eraser is unmodified. So not points 2, 3 atleast.

Comment: OK, "unmodified" removes some.

Comment: +1 Is that your own "Goedel Escher Bach"? :D

Comment: The question is rhetorical, right?  What you want to tell is: "I know that book!".  So yes, it is "Gödel, Escher, Bach" and yes, I own it.

Comment: No I genuinely wanted to know if you had it :p I love that book. Don't forget to use the @

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the eraser is touching the register at more than one points. Rubber often sticks to paper after a long time, like a few days. So, i think, you left the eraser in the register for a day, with more than half of it lying outside. It got stuck then, when you opened the register.

Comment: Good! I didn't think of this. Though this is not the case as in the question; but yes, this could be possible. +1

Answer (score 1):

The notebook is tilted at a steep angle. The eraser balances on the upper edge aided by a little surface friction.

The background is provided by a printed image that has been rotated to make it look like the notebook is being held horizontally.