# Horde of bishops

Tags: lateral-thinking, chess

This has got to be the coolest chess puzzle I have ever seen. Shamelessly stolen from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/what-are-the-features-of-a-well-written-puzzle) (Which is actually linked from the help center, which is how I found this) which links [here](https://braingames.ru/images/main/puzzle/puzzle556.jpg). I don't believe anybody has posted this before as a puzzle though.

The question: **Can white win in this position?**

[image: Chess position]

Comment: No, because black king would always be able to move to the white square? Proly you can do stalemate, but not win.

Comment: @JanIvan Without pawn, true. But... :)

Comment: @ZizyArcher  Depends on where Black pawn ends. If there, there is only one way with enemy bishop moving to A2. If Black pawn has to end here - you wait till black pawn is on A3, then you move bishop from A1/H8 line, and next move after you see King A1+pawn A2, you move it back to A1/H8 line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to solve this before reading below!  (No, really!)

The answer is

> **Yes**

Because

> ```
>   1. B4f6  a6
>   2. Ba1   a5
>   3. Bdg5  a4
>   4. Bgf6  a3
>   5. Kc3   Kxa1   (or: 5. ...Kb1  6. Kb3 a2  7. Kc3 Kxa1  8. Kc2#) 
>   6. Kb3+  Kb1
>   7. Ba1   a2
>   8. Kc3   Kxa1
>   9. Kc2#
> ```
>
> all Black's moves (other than 5) forced.
>  Thanks to Gareth for an enlightening comment in The Sphinx's Lair.

Comment: Why is Black's move 5 forced?

Comment: Not very cute when you had it solved one hour before it was posted…

Comment: @JanIvan I don't know what you mean. I didn't have an answer until just a few minutes before I posted mine.

Comment: Nice :) How did you solve it so fast though?