# Which cup will fill up faster

Tags: visual

[image]

The picture shows the pipe system and the outlets leading to each cup, the question is:

- which of the four cups will fill up faster any why?

Comment: I don't why all the down votes, it s just supposed to be a fun/teaseful problem...

Comment: Yeah I don't know either; seems fine to me. Are trick questions off topic?

Comment: A bit of advice. When I saw this question I immediately thought "Is this a puzzle?" and then "How much effort went into the creation of this puzzle?". This question has probably attracted downvotes because it requires next to no thought or reasoning, just keen observation. What makes matters worse is that this 'problem' is a meme and so it is difficult to give credit, especially when anyone could've made this question in minutes. Have a look at [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5904/56238) for some help on how to make a good puzzle. Anyway, welcome to PE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that

> cup 5 is the only cup that will fill up, because if you look closely at the pipes, all the other cups' pipes are blocked at some point.